# Extract strings from user input URL Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http

A user on my site will enter a url of the form

```
    url = "https://www.website.com/shop/SHOPNAME/location/LOCATION"
```

I would like to extract the `SHOPNAME` and `LOCATION` substrings. The structure of the input url will always be of this form (or at least if they are not I will return an error). I have found answers on how to parse out particular characters, a certain suffix or a certain prefix but not two different substrings.

I require these strings to make an HTTP get request to my server. The alternative to extracting the strings, if I could send the full url over the HTTP request I can change my server side application easily for what is required. To do this I would need to prepend ever / with a \ (I think) - so alternatively if anyone had a solution for that it would be amazing!

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the structure of the input url will always be of that form, You can simply do:

```
url = "https://www.website.com/shop/SHOPNAME/location/LOCATION"
var subString = url.split( '/' );
var shopName = subString[4];
var shopLocation = subString[6];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution using a regex.

```js
let url = "https://www.website.com/shop/SHOPNAME/location/LOCATION"
let regex = /\/shop\/(.*)\/location\/(.*)/i;
let matches = regex.exec(url);
if (matches.length === 3) {
  let shopname = matches[1];
  let location = matches[2];
  console.log(shopname, location);
}
```